# How to compute "EMD" for 2 numpy arrays i.e "histogram" using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, histogram, earthdistance

Since I'm new to opencv, I don't know how to use the [`cv.CalcEMD2`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#emd) function with `numpy` arrays.
I have two arrays:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]  
b=[1,2,3,4]
```

How can I transfer `numpy array` to `CVhistogram` and from `Cvhistogram` to the function parameter `signature`?

I would like anyone who answers the question to explain any used `opencv` functions through the provided solution.

"EMD" == [earth mover's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).

Update:-
also ,It will be helpful if anyone can tell me how to set the [`cv.CalcEMD2`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#emd) parameter i.e`"signature"` using `numpy` array!!

Note:-
 * For those who may be interested in this question ,This answer needs more testing.

Comment: @JaimeCervantes , I saw your solution about "EMD" ,but since I don't understand `OpenCV` data structure so well,I figured you can modify your answer to suit my question.Thankx.

Comment: considering this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101004/python-code-for-earth-movers-distance?lq=1

Comment: I think I know how to do it, I'll look at it over the weekend

Comment: @JaimeCervantes I hope so.I'm looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to define your arrays in terms of weights and coordinates. If you have two arrays a = [1,1,0,0,1] and b = [0,1,0,1] that represent one dimensional histograms, then the numpy arrays should look like this:

```
a = [[1 1]
     [1 2]
     [0 3]
     [0 4]
     [1 5]]

b = [[0 1]
     [1 2]
     [0 3]
     [1 4]]
```

Notice that the number of rows can be different. The number of columns should be the dimensions + 1. The first column contains the weights, and the second column contains the coordinates.

The next step is to convert your arrays to a CV_32FC1 Mat before you input the numpy array as a signature to the CalcEMD2 function. The code would look like this:

```
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np

# Initialize a and b numpy arrays with coordinates and weights
a = np.zeros((5,2))

for i in range(0,5):
    a[i][1] = i+1

a[0][0] = 1
a[1][0] = 1
a[2][0] = 0
a[3][0] = 0
a[4][0] = 1

b = np.zeros((4,2))

for i in range(0,4):
    b[i][1] = i+1

b[0][0] = 0
b[1][0] = 1
b[2][0] = 0
b[3][0] = 1    

# Convert from numpy array to CV_32FC1 Mat
a64 = cv.fromarray(a)
a32 = cv.CreateMat(a64.rows, a64.cols, cv.CV_32FC1)
cv.Convert(a64, a32)

b64 = cv.fromarray(b)
b32 = cv.CreateMat(b64.rows, b64.cols, cv.CV_32FC1)
cv.Convert(b64, b32)

# Calculate Earth Mover's
print cv.CalcEMD2(a32,b32,cv.CV_DIST_L2)

# Wait for key
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

Notice that the third parameter of CalcEMD2 is the Euclidean Distance CV_DIST_L2. Another option for the third parameter is the Manhattan Distance CV_DIST_L1.

I would also like to mention that I wrote the code to calculate the Earth Mover's distance of two 2D histograms in Python. You can find this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101004/python-code-for-earth-movers-distance/10670028#10670028).

Comment: The time is almost over for the bounty, are you selecting an answer?

Comment: If `a=[15,23,14]` ,what is the corresponding array **with coordinates and weights**?

Comment: Testing the code,returns "0.0". Is it normal despite of the difference between the two arrays?

Comment: If the arrays are different, there should be a distance greater than zero. I tested different arrays with my code ant it was working.

Comment: @Someone did you got the code to work? I reviewed my OpenCV book and edited my post to include a better description of the code.

Comment: Of course, `np.zeros(4,2)` should be `np.zeros((4,2))`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the function `cv.CalcEMD2` is gone in OpenCV 3.0.0-beta, and the replacement function `EMD` [does not have Python bindings](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3406).

Answer (score 3):

CV.CalcEMD2 expects arrays that also include the weight for each signal according to the documentation.

I would suggest defining your arrays with a weight of 1, like so:

```
a=array([1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1])
b=array([1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1])
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP wanted to measure [Earth Mover's Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) using OpenCV, but if you'd like to do so using Scipy, you can use the following (Wasserstein Distance is also known as Earth Mover's Distance):

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
from scipy.ndimage import imread
import numpy as np

def get_histogram(img):
  '''
  Get the histogram of an image. For an 8-bit, grayscale image, the
  histogram will be a 256 unit vector in which the nth value indicates
  the percent of the pixels in the image with the given darkness level.
  The histogram's values sum to 1.
  '''
  h, w = img.shape
  hist = [0.0] * 256
  for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
      hist[img[i, j]] += 1
  return np.array(hist) / (h * w)

a = imread('a.jpg')
b = imread('b.jpg')
a_hist = get_histogram(a)
b_hist = get_histogram(b)
dist = wasserstein_distance(a_hist, b_hist)
print(dist)
```

Comment: This may is not 100% true anymore. `wasserstein_distance` cannot handle histograms it expects values observed in the (empirical) distribution as 1D vector. So simply flatten the image arrays and pass it through the function. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html