# Function CalcEMD2 missing from OpenCV3 module for Anaconda Python

Tags: python, opencv

I need to calculate the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD) in my program. I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670028/6017941), but for some reason the `cv2` module which I have on my system does not have the function `CalcEMD2`. Could someone explain why it is missing?

I am using Anaconda for Python 3.4 and installed OpenCV with

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

The package installed without problems and imports nicely.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
3.1.0
```

However, `CalcEMD2` does not exist. The namespace of `cv2` has only two members containing the string 'emd' (case-insensitive), neither of which is the function I'm looking for:

```
>>> [k for k in cv2.__dict__ if 'emd' in k.lower()]
['createEMDHistogramCostExtractor', 'createEMDL1HistogramCostExtractor']
```

Comment: The new name is `EMD`, so it should be like: `cv2.EMD(...)`

Comment: In my case there is neither `cv2.EMD`. I edited the question to show that the module contains only two functions containing the string 'EMD' in their name, but neither of them is the one that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it under cv2.cv.CalcEMD2() for most OpenCV 2.7.x libraries I've seen.

The compareHist() also has parameters hiding under cv2.cv.CV_COMP_* as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, `CalcEMD2` is there in the OpenCV 2.4.x libs for Python 2.7, but it seems to be missing from OpenCV 3.1.x libs for Python 3.x.

Comment: Cool, I see you mentioned Python 3.4. I was looking for the same function in Python 2.7 and the cv2.cv.* was a problem leading to this question. Hope, the solution comes up for Python 3.